# In Luke 11:42–43 did Jesus have Micah 6:8 in mind?

Tags: jesus, luke, new-testament, micah

See the matching with [A], [B], and [C].

“But woe to you Pharisees! For you tithe mint and rue and every herb, and neglect justice [A] and the love of God [B]. These you ought to have done, without neglecting the others. 43 Woe to you Pharisees! For you love the best seat in the synagogues and greetings in the marketplaces. [C]
(Luke 11:42–43, ESV)

```
   He has told you, O man, what is good; 
  and what does the LORD require of you   
              but to do justice [A], and to love kindness (חֶ֔סֶד), [B]
  and to walk humbly with your God? [C]
                             (Micah 6:8, ESV)
```

For meaning oh hesed (חֶ֔סֶד) see [What does it mean when God says that he desires mercy and not sacrifice according Hosea 6:6](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/40822/what-does-it-mean-when-god-says-that-he-desires-mercy-and-not-sacrifice-accordin/68304#68304)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OT contains a repeated pattern of the "required" behavior of God's people which can be summarized the following table:

| Matt 23:23 | Justice | Mercy | Faithfulness |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Micah 6:8 | Act justly | Love mercy | Walk humbly before God |
| Jer 7:3-6 | Deal justly | Do not oppress the alien, widow, etc | Don’t follow other gods |
| Jer 9:24 | Justice | kindness | Righteousness |
| James 1:26, 27 | -- | Care for orphans | Unpolluted by world |
| Isa 58:3-14 | Loose chains of injustice | Share food & clothes | Keep Sabbath |
| Zech 7:4-14 | Administer true justice | Show mercy and compassion, do not oppress widows, orphans, alien, and poor | Listen to the Word of the Lord |
| Psalm 112 | V5: Good will come to him…who conducts his affairs with justice | V9: He has scattered abroad his gifts to the poor | V1: Blessed is the man who fears the Lord |

The passage in Luke 11:42, 43 is essentially parallel to Matt 23:23 which has a verbal parallel to Micah 6:8.  Another passage might also be included here:

> Hos 6:6 - For I desire mercy, not sacrifice, and the knowledge of God
> rather than burnt offerings.

Thus, while the verbal parallel of Matt 23:23 & Luke 11:42, 43 is primarily to Micah 6:8, the other passages above appeared to echoed in Jesus' meaning.

Comment: [Tzedakah v'chesed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avinu_Malkeinu).